# Building array of objects from parsed csv files in node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, csv, object

I have multiple csv files of the form

- model1A
- model1B
- model2A
- model2B

where each csv is an array i.e. `model1A = [1, 1, 1]`

I want to parse these csvs and create a single array containing all these models, where each element in the array is an object corresponding to one particular model, i.e.

```
finalArray = [ 
  { 
    "model" :   "model1",
    "A"     :   [1, 1, 1],
    "B"     :   [2, 2, 2]
  },
  { 
    "model" :   "model2",
    "A"     :   [3, 3, 3],
    "B"     :   [4, 4, 4]
  }
]
```

The code I have so far is

```
var csv = require('csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var parser = csv.parse();
var util = require('util');
var junk = require('junk');
var _ = require('lodash');
var models = [];


fs.readdir(__dirname+'/data', function(err, files) {
    var model = {};
    _.forEach(files, function(n, key) {

        console.log('Analysing file: ' + n);
        var modelName;
        var modelNum;
        var modelParam;


        modelNum = n.match(/\d+/)[0];
        modelName = 'model' + modelNum;
        modelParam = (n.substring(0, n.indexOf('.'))).replace(modelName,'');

        model.model = modelName;
        model[modelParam] = [];
        models.push(model);

        //if (Object.keys(model).length === 3) {
        //    models.push(model);
        //    model = {};
        //}


        fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/data/'+n).pipe(csv.parse()).pipe(csv.transform(function(row) {
            model[modelParam].push(row);

        })).on('readable', function(){
            while(this.read()){}
        }).on('end', function() {
            console.log('finished reading file ' + n);
            if (key === (files.length - 1)) {
                fs.writeFile('result.json', JSON.stringify(models), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(models.length + ' model(s) parsed');
                    console.log('done');
                });
            }

        }).on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });    
    });
});
```

I know one of my issues is I am pushing the model to the array to soon, resulting in a final array of the form below, where `model1` is being overwritten by `model2`

```
[ { model: 'model2', A: [], B: [] },
  { model: 'model2', A: [], B: [] },
  { model: 'model2', A: [], B: [] },
  { model: 'model2', A: [], B: [] } ]
```

That's why I tried this code

```
if (Object.keys(model).length === 3) {
  models.push(model);
  model = {};
}
```

but of course this couldn't work because the `fs.createReadStream` is async and I am clearing the model with `model = {}` before it can run properly.

I'm at the stage now where I feel I'm going around in circles and just making things worse. I wanted to create something more generic, however, now I would be delighted to get it working for the case presented here and then I can look at improving it.

Any help would be really appreciated!

---

### Update 1

Following saquib khan's suggestion of moving the `var model = {}` inside the loop has helped get me closer to my goal, but it's still not right. Below is the current result

```
[
    {
        "model": "model1",
        "A": [
            [
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "3"
            ],
            [
                "4"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "model1",
        "B": [
            [
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "3"
            ],
            [
                "4"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "model2",
        "A": [
            [
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "3"
            ],
            [
                "4"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "model2",
        "B": [
            [
                "1"
            ],
            [
                "2"
            ],
            [
                "3"
            ],
            [
                "4"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

---

### Update 2

Also following Denys Denysiuk's suggestion, the result is closer to what I want, but still just short

```
[
    {
        "model": "model1",
        "A": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "model1",
        "B": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "model2",
        "A": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    },
    {
        "model": "model2",
        "B": [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4"
        ]
    }
]
```

This would work, if I could just somehow iterate over that final array of objects, merging objects with a matching `model` name. I'm currently looking through the [lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs) to see if I can figure something out. I will post back here if I do.

Comment: Seems, `row` is array. You can try `model[modelParam].push(row[0]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
fs.readdir(__dirname+'/data', function(err, files) {

    _.forEach(files, function(n, key) {

        console.log('Analysing file: ' + n);            

        var modelNum = n.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var modelName = 'model' + modelNum;
        var modelParam = (n.substring(0, n.indexOf('.'))).replace(modelName,'');

        var model = {};
        var isNewModel = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
            if(models[i].model == modelName) {
               model = models[i];
               isNewModel = false;
               break;
            }
        }
        if(isNewModel) {
            model.model = modelName;
            models.push(model);
        }

        model[modelParam] = [];

        fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/data/'+n).pipe(csv.parse()).pipe(csv.transform(function(row) {
            model[modelParam].push(row[0]);

        })).on('readable', function(){
            while(this.read()){}
        }).on('end', function() {
            console.log('finished reading file ' + n);
            if (key === (files.length - 1)) {
                fs.writeFile('result.json', JSON.stringify(models), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(models.length + ' model(s) parsed');
                    console.log('done');
                });
            }

        }).on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });    
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was and how you suggest to fix it

Comment: Problem was in new model in each iteration. Solution is try to find existing model, if it is not found - create new one.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very small coding error in your code.

**var model = {};** should be inside forEach loop.

Try below code:

```
var csv = require('csv');
var fs = require('fs');
var parser = csv.parse();
var util = require('util');
var junk = require('junk');
var _ = require('lodash');
var models = [];


fs.readdir(__dirname+'/data', function(err, files) {

    _.forEach(files, function(n, key) {

        console.log('Analysing file: ' + n);
        var model = {};
        var modelName;
        var modelNum;
        var modelParam;


        modelNum = n.match(/\d+/)[0];
        modelName = 'model' + modelNum;
        modelParam = (n.substring(0, n.indexOf('.'))).replace(modelName,'');

        model.model = modelName;
        model[modelParam] = [];
        models.push(model);

        //if (Object.keys(model).length === 3) {
        //    models.push(model);
        //    model = {};
        //}


        fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/data/'+n).pipe(csv.parse()).pipe(csv.transform(function(row) {
            model[modelParam].push(row);

        })).on('readable', function(){
            while(this.read()){}
        }).on('end', function() {
            console.log('finished reading file ' + n);
            if (key === (files.length - 1)) {
                fs.writeFile('result.json', JSON.stringify(models), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(models.length + ' model(s) parsed');
                    console.log('done');
                });
            }

        }).on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is event driven so maybe you could base your code using the Event module: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Your problem seems like you are overriding previous entries in your array, so maybe you should go to the next step (reading the other CSV ?) only when the previous one has finished to write everything it needed to.

You can add this logic to your code with Event.